# Modules that have only finitely many submodules

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, modules, lattice-orders

Drawing the lattice of submodules of a given module helps me to gain some intuition about the structure of module. Sometimes, however, it is not possible to draw in neat manner; For example vector spaces may have infinitely many subspaces. What is a good class of modules to draw the lattice of submodules in neat manner? (Uniserial modules are candidate which I know of.) An answer to this question might be somewhere, but I don't know. Lastly, let me make my questions clear.

1. What is a (large enough) class of modules that have only finitely many submodules (NOT up to isomorphic)?
2. <del>What is a (large enough) class of rings or algebras that every (finitely generated) right modules have only finitely many submodules?</del> Solved owing to Jeremy Rickard's answer.

Comment: A subclass of modules with finitely many submodules would be very tiny, even smaller than the class of Artinian modules over a ring. Even a two dimensional module over the rational numbers has infinitely many submodules. I suppose it would contain the class of simple modules though. These classes are not even closed under finite direct sums...

Comment: Maybe the question gets more interesting if you include the assumption of your modules being "indecomposable"?

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer To eliminate examples like the one which J. Rickard proposed?  I'm not sure how it affects... (be complicated or be clear?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A satisfactory answer to my question 1 was given in [Jan57, Lemma 1.2, Corollary 1.3] (or [Ful79, Proposition 1.3]). In particular, for a finite dimensional algebra over an infinite field, a finitely generated module has finitely many submodules if and only if it is distributive (*i.e.*, the lattice of submodules is distributive). Such modules are characterized by the socle of factors [Cam75, Theorem 1]: A module is distributive if and only if every factor has square-free socle.

- [Cam75] V. CAMILLO, 'Distributive modules', *J. Algebra* 36 (1975) 16-25, doi:[10.1016/0021-8693(75)90151-9](http://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(75)90151-9). [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=573061) [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0308.16015)
- [Ful79] K. FULLER, 'Biserial rings', *Ring Theory Waterloo 1978*, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 734 (eds D. Handelman and J. Lawrence; Springer-Verlag, 1979) 64-90, doi:[10.1007/BFb0103154](http://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0103154). [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=548124) [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0411.16023)
- [Jan57] J. JANS, 'On the indecomposable representations of algebras', *Ann. of Math.* 66 (1957) 418-429, doi:[10.2307/1969899](http://doi.org/10.2307/1969899). [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=88485) [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0079.05203)

Answer (score 6):

For the second question, the finite rings are precisely those for which every finitely generated module has finitely many submodules.

For a ring $R$ and $r\in R$, let $M_r$ be the submodule of $R\oplus R$ generated by $(1,r)$. Then $(1,r)$ is the only element of $M_r$ whose first coordinate is $1$, and so $M_r\neq M_s$ for $r\neq s$, and so if $R$ is infinite then the modules $\{M_r\mid r\in R\}$ form an infinite set of submodules of $R\oplus R$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your best bet for both questions will be to consider finite rings and their finitely generated modules. These at least will be closed under products.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper on modules with finitely many submodus, by
Akbari, Khalashi Ghezelahmad and Yaraneri.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The statements you implied in your answer seem to be Lemma 2.3 and Theorem 2.4 in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0219498815501169). Though it is closely related to my question, it seems to me it does't answer my question fully.